# TextChanged/LostFocus/etc. event for DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a list of object bound to a `DataGrid` in a WPF page and I am looking to add an object directly after the current one if the value entered in a specific column is less than a certain number.

```
<my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Hours}"/>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to bind to an event on the underlying `TextBox`. Various sites reference the ability to do this but none provide the associated code. For now I have been using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `TextBox` inside of it  but I don't seem to the able to get the current row with that solution.

Comment: can you be more specific in what event you need to get at, there might be a more elegant solution than events if we could know the reason.

Comment: I am trying to add additional rows dynamically after the current when the value in a specific column was changed to be below a certain number. Events might not be the answer but I know not enough about DataGrid to figure out otherwise. I had been experimenting with binding to TextChanged or LostFocus on a TextBox in a DataGridTemplateColumn which worked but as I said was unable to determine the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accomplish this I used the `CellEditEnding` event on the data grid itself.

```
this.TheGrid.CellEditEnding += new EventHandler<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs>(TheGrid_CellEditEnding);
```

In the method you can then use a `Dispatcher` to delay the call to a method so the value is stored back in the bound object.

```
private void TheGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(this.CellEdited));
}
```

You can also pass the `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` to the method to allow you to inspect the row and column of the cell that was edited along with the underlying `TextBox`.

Also since the data grid is concerned about objects the row index is not too relevant and therefore not easily obtainable (that I could find).

Comment: It is not triggered when a row is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can used this code for all cell and row updated:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" CellEditEnded="DataGrid_CellEditEnded" RowEditEnded="DataGrid_RowEditEnded">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Hours}" Width="Auto" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```